# Apostol, Ch. 1 Linear Spaces: Replace positivity axiom with $(x,x)=0 \iff x=O$. Prove $(x,x)>0$ for all $x\neq O$ or else $(x,x)<0$ for all $x\neq O$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products

The following is a problem from Chapter 1 "Linear Spaces" from Apostol's *Calculus* (section 1.13)

> 2. Suppose we retain the first three axioms for a real inner product (symmetry, linearity, and homogeneity) but replace the fourth axiom by
>    a new axiom: $(x,x)=0 \iff x=O$. Prove that either $(x,x)>0$ for all
>    $x\neq O$ or else $(x,x)<0$ for all $x\neq O$.
>
> [Hint: Assume $(x,x)>0$ for some $x\neq O$ and $(y,y)<0$ for some
> $y\neq O$. In the space spanned by $\{x,y\}$ find an element $z\neq O$
> with $(z,z)=0$.]

My question is if the solution below is correct.

**Here is my attempt at a solution**

Assume $(x,x)>0$ and $(y,y)>0$ for some elements $x$ and $y$ neither equal to the zero element, $O$.

Let $z=c_1x+c_2y$ be any element in the space spanned by $x$ and $y$.

Assume $c_2=1$. Then

$$(z,z)=(x,x)c_1^2+2(x,y)c_1+(y,y)=0$$

If we try to solve this for $c_1$ we find

$$\Delta=4[(x,y)^2-(x,x)(y,y)]$$

Now, if we were dealing with the usual axioms for a real inner product we could say that $\Delta\leq 0$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But it seems that this inequality does not follow given our new fourth axiom.

Thus we can solve for $c_1$ obtaining

$$c_1=\frac{-(x,y)\pm\sqrt{(x,y)-(x,x)(y,y)}}{(x,x)}$$

In addition, $z$ is not the zero element because if it were then we'd have

$$x+z=(1+c_1)x+y=x$$

$$y=-c_1x$$

and $(y,y)=(-c_1x,-c_1x)=c_1^2(x,x)\geq 0$

which contradicts our assumption that $(y,y)<0$.

Thus, $z$ is not the zero element.

That is, given any nonzero $x$ and $y$ with $(x,x)>0$ and $(y,y)<0$ we have found a $z=c_1x+y$ such that $(z,z)=0$ and $z\neq O$. But this contradicts the new axiom from this problem.

Comment: May help : pick $x_1, y_1$ with the properties $\langle x_1, x_1\rangle=1$ , $\langle y_1, y_1\rangle =-1 $ and $\langle x_1, y_1\rangle =0$ then $0\neq z=x+y$ have the property $\langle z, z\rangle =0$